# IE6 - body shrink on hover / z-index change

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I'm debugging a site to make it work for IE6 (god, please, let this be the last time). I've gotten pretty far with getting the the layout look right. There's just one more thing bugging me.

1. Some elements like links, when they get hovered, the body of the site shrinks.
2. I have built a dropdown with javascript. When it should show, the body of the site shrinks.
3. There is a slideshow, made with javascript, which changes the z-index of the images, everytime it changes the z-index, the body shrinks.

Now I found some information that IE6 creates this specific shrinking behaviour when using a fixed position element. But this is not the case. Someone here have some ideas for solving this? Thanks!

Comment: "god, please, let this be the last time".... not a chance, fella

Comment: This would be a lot easier if we had some source code to look at.

Answer (score 1):

I use situations like these as an argument to convince the users to finally switch from this monstrosity of a browser.

Comment: "Youtube doesn't support it and they have millions of viewers every day!" is my favourite argument for non IE6 use.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to ask the question.... but are you using?:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Enter "special" styles for IE 6
<![endif]-->
```

It will get you out of a jam.

Regarding dropping IE6 support for sites, I have found that complaining to clients about it doesn't work very often.  But what does work is showing them in their Google Analytics that only 5% of their site visitors use it, and its ok if it doesn't match exactly, as long as the content is accessible.  That niche 5% costs a lot of extra development time and money to cater too.  But your screwed if it says 11% :-)

Comment: All the time!

What solved all issues in the end was the following:

html { width:100%; height:100%; overflow:scroll; }
body { width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; }

the overflow setup was very important in this matter apparently